# Type of T forSome{type T}

Tags: scala, type-systems, existential-type

I am going through [drmacvier](http://www.drmaciver.com/2008/03/existential-types-in-scala/) blog about existential types in Scala. After reading it I was experimenting with types and I am checking the equality of types in the following manner as given in [rnduja](http://rnduja.github.io/2015/10/07/scala-dependent-types/) blog.

```
def implicitly[A](implicit a: A) = a

// To check equality of two types
class =:=[A, B]
implicit def equalTypeInstance[A] = new =:=[A, A]
def type_==[A, B](implicit ev: A =:= B = null) = ev != null

// To check subtype relation between two types
class <:<[-A, +B]
implicit def subTypeInstance[A] = new <:<[A, A]
def type_<[A, B](implicit ev: A <:< B = null) = ev != null
```

The first thing I checked was this:

```
type_==[Any, T forSome{type T}] // true
```

what I could not understand is `T forSome{type T}` is satisfied by any type but why is its type `Any`. Assuming, since `Any` is common ancestor of all possible types it makes sense that they are are equal. In the similar way I was able to reason about.

```
type_==[Array[Any], Array[T forSome{type T}]] // true
type_==[List[Any], List[T forSome{type T}]] // true
```

I was not able to get this right with the same reasoning.

```
type_==[Array[Any], (Array[T] forSome{type T})] // false
type_==[List[Any], (List[T] forSome{type T})] // true
```

what am I missing here ? Is my way of reasoning flawed ?

Comment: Probably because List is covariant and Array is invariant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what I could not understand is T forSome{type T} is satisfied by any type but why is its type Any

Any *value* (not any type) has some type (at least type `Any`). So it has type `T` for some type `T`. But this means it also has type `T forSome { type T }`. So any value of type `Any` has type `T forSome { type T }` (and vice versa).

For the first two comparisons: if `A` is equal to `B`, then `F[A]` should be equal to `F[B]`, whatever `F` is. You've just checked that `Any` and `T forSome {type T}` are equal, so... But you simply can't use the same reasoning for the other two cases: what would `A`, `B` and `F` be?

`Array[Any]` is not the same as `Array[T] forSome { type T }`, because let's say you have a value

```
val array: Array[String] = Array("a")
```

Then it has type `Array[T] forSome { type T }` (do you understand why?):

```
val arrayForSome: Array[T] forSome { type T } = array // compiles
```

but

```
val arrayOfAny: Array[Any] = array
```

doesn't compile (because `Array` is invariant). So clearly `Array[T] forSome { type T }` and `Array[Any]` are different: a value can have one of these types without having the other.